# add title attr to somewhere to existing html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish I can insert the title attr to the existed html. not sure is it possible..

http://jsfiddle.net/9X53k/

```
var existedHtml = "<li><a href='#'>some item</a></li>"

$('div').append(existedHtml);

// if user did some option run the below code..
// it doesnt work that way btw..
$(existedHtml).find('a').attr('title','work?');
```

Comment: I think some sample code of the what the function that's creating the elements is returning would help in answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo now i know what you want and this is the solutions

```
var existedHtml = "<li><a href='#'>some item</a></li>"

var tester = $('div').append(existedHtml);

// if user did some option run the below code..
// it doesnt work that way btw..
tester.find('a').attr('title','work?');
```

What you did before did not work because the element was already added to the dom

http://jsfiddle.net/9X53k/2/

Comment: nope.. I update my question, hope u helps :)

Comment: Done and its working! :)

Comment: if I select the existedHtml variable to use attr it doesn't seem work, why i need a new variable, test? maybe it need to be appended 1st?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it with jQuery

```
$(somePredifinedHTML).attr('title','myTitle');
```

if you want to give  the title you can use find

```
$(somePredifinedHTML).find('a').attr('title','myTitle');
```

**Update**

You must save the html after you change it like this

```
var existedHtml = "<li><a href='#'>some item</a></li>"
existedHtml = $(existedHtml).find('a').attr('title','work?');    
$('div').append(existedHtml);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/9X53k/1/)

Comment: @downvoter isn't this what OP wants?

Comment: who the hell voted down all the answer..

Comment: @RickiVandenbroek I would like to know aswell :)

Comment: sound logic but this doesn't work